# Is is able to finish activity jumped by intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent('some system ui activty not in my application');
startActivity(intent);
```

I delay a certain time then jump back to myself activity, However the SystemActivity is still back in history. How to finish it? I tried nohistory ,excludeFromRecents and start my activity with clearTop, but nothing can be done.

The problem is, if the SystemActivty go to some other page by user, I cannot use Intent to jump to the first page of SystemActivity, which maybe make user confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the systemActivity to end before returning to the mainActivity try
`startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```